# ¿Como deshabilitar una fila en un datagridview al presionar un botón y que quede deshabilitada al cargar el formulario?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

tengo el siguiente código para "deshabilitar" la fila seleccionada en un `DataGridView`

```
     private void btnEliminar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
            if(dgvProveedor.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                int filaElimar = dgvProveedor.CurrentRow.Index;
                dgvProveedor.CurrentCell = null;                        
                dgvProveedor.Rows[filaElimar].ReadOnly = false;
                dgvProveedor.Rows[filaElimar].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
            }
    }
```

La fila primero se selecciona la fila que se va a deshabilitar y al presionar el botón se deshabilita y le agregue un color para dar sentido de que esta deshabilitada. Pero cuando cierro la aplicación y la vuelvo a iniciar, la fila que "Elimine" vuelve a estar "Habilitada", como hago para que se quede deshabilitada al cerrar e iniciar la aplicación? Utilizo `C#` en `visual studio 2017`

Comment: deshabilitala desde cuando se inicia la aplicacion y no desde el evento del boton.

Comment: despues de esta instanciacion InitializeComponent(); puerdes poner tu codigo para que cuando se cierres y vuelvas abrirlo lo primero que haga es deshabilitar tu columna

Comment: @Manny ok, no entendi muy bien, yo primero la selecciono y la deshabilito con el botón, porque se tiene que escoger la que se quiera deshabilitar, pero como lo paso al InitializeComponent()?

Comment: te comente en base a lo que poner en tu pregunta, aun hay informacion que falta, por ejemplo, es un formulario hijo?  es el formulario principal?

Comment: es informacion escencial agregala a tu pregunta...

Comment: @Manny es un formulario hijo

Comment: ¿Qué gestor de base de datos usas? Para deshabilitar una fila y que siga así aunque el programa se cierre y se vuelva abrir, necesitarías almacenar en la DB el índice de la fila que está deshabilitado y cargarlo en el constructor del formulario y de este modo sabrás que filas no estarán disponibles. Y cuando el usuario habilite de nuevo la fila, pues necesitarás eliminar el índice de dicha fila de la base de datos.

Comment: @MrDave1999 uso Sql Sever

Comment: Encontraste la solución?